# raw_input() won't show prompt until after input

Tags: python, python-2.7, raw-input

It actually goes further than the title suggests, if I have raw_input() anywhere in main, nothing will happen until the input has been entered by the user including any function calls or outputs that should occur before raw_input is called.  Here's a very simple example of my code and what occurs when it's run.

```
def main():
    answer = raw_input('Continue?')
    print 'You said: ', answer
```

When I run it:
(nothing comes on screen)

(user input)

```
blah blah blah
```

(Output):

```
Continue?You said: blah blah blah
```

I apologize if this is some sort of absurdly simple fix, but I've searched quite a bit and not been able to find anything.  I'm running Windows 7 64 bit with Python 2.7 if that has anything to do with it.  Also, identical code works perfectly in the interpreter which is kind of weird.  If you guys can figure this out, that would be great!

Thanks,
Will

Edit: Just tried to work around by using `sys.stdin.readline()` but had the same issue.

Comment: How are you executing the code?

Comment: Just running it from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it was a buffering issue.  I solved it by entering the '-u' command.