# Learning Python the Hard Way (Third Edition) Exercise 11 Print statements not printed until after input is entered

Tags: python, printing, cygwin, raw-input

Learning Python the Hard Way (Third Edition) states to use Powershell if one is using MS Windows.

I downloaded cygwin in an effort to emulate a linux environment as Zed Shaw states Linux is acceptable.

The first 10 exercises were successfully executed without a hitch.

Unfortunately, I encountered a problem with Exercise 11 "Asking Questions".

$ more ex11.py

```
print "How old are you?",
age = raw_input()
print "How tall are you?",
height = raw_input()
print "How much do you weigh?",
weight = raw_input()

print "So, you're %r old, %r tall and %r heavy." % (age, height, weight)
```

Running the `.py` file results in print statements only being printed after three lines of input are provided?

$ python ex11.py

```
32
6'2"
180 lbs

How old are you? How tall are you? How much do you weigh? So, you're '32' old, '6\'2"' tall and '180 lbs' heavy.
```

Curious.

Might anyone be able to offer an explanation and a solution?

Thanks!

-Python Newbie

Comment: Are you sure there are commas at the end of the print statements?

Comment: Your code works correctly for me, so the Python side is ok. There must be some problem with the powershell. And why not pass your questions as parameters to `raw_input`? (That's how they are supposed to be used.) E.g. `age = raw_input("How old are you? ")`

Comment: Sorry, realised they were there to prevent new lines. Does anything appear if you execute the code and wait for ~10s?

Comment: Just to make it explicit: PowerShell is _not_ being used, the problem occurs in _Cygwin_.

Answer (score 0):

I found this stack overflow post that describes a similar symptom...
[raw_input() won't show prompt until after input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621082/raw-input-wont-show-prompt-until-after-input)

The cause therein is cited as a buffering problem.

The recommended solution therein states to run python using the -u option.

Checking the python help pages:

$ python -h

...

-u     : unbuffered binary stdout and stderr; also PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x
         see man page for details on internal buffering relating to '-u'

...

Turns out that appears to have fixed my problem as well - at least in the SHORT TERM.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

$ python -u ex11.py

How old are you? 32

How tall are you? 6'2"

How much do you weigh? 180

So, you're '32' old, '6\'2"' tall and '180' heavy.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Unfortunately,.. it appears if I ever want to run that one .py file I HAVE to use the -u option. It's not like the buffer was permanently cleared. :(

Another attempt seconds later resulted in the same initial problem.

$ python ex11.py

32

6'2"

180

How old are you? How tall are you? How much do you weigh? So, you're '32' old, '6\'2"' tall and '180' heavy.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Is there a LONG TERM FIX?

Comment: Exercise 12 is similar in nature

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

$ more ex12.py

age = raw_input("How old are you? ")

height = raw_input("How tall are you? ")

weight = raw_input("How much do you weigh? ")

print "So, you're %r old, %r tall and %r heavy." % (
        age, height, weight)

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

The results were the same as ex11.py

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

- i.e. the python -u option needed to be specific in order for it to run as expected.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Please [format your code properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Answer (score 0):

At the start of every Cygwin (`bash`) session, run:

```
export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
```

*or*, for a persistent solution, add that line to your `~/.bashrc` file; e.g.:

```
echo 'export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1' >> ~/.bashrc
```

This saves you from having to pass `-u` to the `python` executable every time, and therefore enables direct invocation of `*.py` files.

Defining environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` with a value of `1` and command-line option `-u` both have the following effect, which, as you've discovered, solves your problem (from the [v2.7 docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u)):

> Force stdin, stdout and stderr to be totally unbuffered. On systems where it matters, also put stdin, stdout and stderr in binary mode.
>
> Note that there is internal buffering in file.readlines() and File Objects (for line in sys.stdin) which is not influenced by this option. To work around this, you will want to use file.readline() inside a while 1: loop.

---

Note: **This is only necessary because of your unusual setup:** combining Cygwin with a *Windows* `python` executable (I presume).

By contrast, running your Windows `python` from a regular Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`) or PowerShell console (`powershell.exe`) would *not* exhibit this problem.