# raw_input prints prompt after asking for input

Tags: python, python-2.x, raw-input

When I use raw_input, the prompt only shows after the user gives input. Like this:

```
number = raw_input("Enter a number:")
```

but when I run this, nothing happens, the I type a number, the it shows the prompt:

```
123
Enter a number:
```

(123 used to be blank until I typed a number and hit enter)

I just want the prompt to display before the user input. If anybody knows how to fix this please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this running in a script at a regular terminal, an IDE's terminal, IDLE, something else? Likely it's an issue with a terminal emulator that doesn't quite support the features `raw_input` uses to flush `sys.stdout` prior to displaying the prompt.

Comment: Likely related to [raw_input() won't show prompt until after input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11621082/364696), but the answer there is poor; not willing to mark as duplicate.

Comment: I am running with a Git bash terminal, but when I run it in CMD it works.

Answer (score 0):

You might be in an environment where your standard output is buffered and won't flush until there is a newline character.

You can take advantage of the fact the standard error is unbuffered and redirect standard output to standard error instead:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = sys.stderr
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you suggestion, and I did try that, but unfortunately it didn't work, but I did find the solution:

I had to add

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

before each time I had a

```
variable = raw_input("A prompt")
```

to flush the buffer.

Although for the first

```
raw_input("A prompt")
```

it will not work work unless you already printed something, for example

```
variable = raw_input("A prompt")
sys.stdout.flush()
```

would still have the same issue, whereas

```
print"Welcome,"

variable = raw_input("A prompt")
sys.stdout.flush()
```

would work.